# How to go from blocking vertx future to RxJava Observable

Tags: rx-java, future, blocking, vert.x

I saw code like this in our repo.

```
   public Observable<Optional<DeviceInfo>> getDeviceInfo(final String userAgent) {
        final ObservableFuture<Optional<DeviceInfo>> observable = RxHelper.observableFuture();
        vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
            try {
                final Optional<Device> device = Optional.ofNullable(engine.get().getDeviceForRequest(userAgent));
                if (device.isPresent()) {
                    future.complete(Optional.of(new DeviceInfo()));
                } else {
                    future.complete(Optional.empty());
                }
            } catch (final RuntimeException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Unable to get the UA device info {}, reason {}", userAgent, e.getMessage());
                future.fail(e.getMessage());
            }
        }, observable.toHandler());

        return observable.single();
    }
```

For me it seems a little strange to write that much code to go from executing this blocking code and map the future to a single Observable.

Isn't there an easier and better way to do exactly this? e.g. some convenience factory method etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [Vert.x API for RxJava](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java/) and `Optional.map`:

```
public Single<Optional<DeviceInfo>> getDeviceInfo(final String userAgent) {
  return vertx.rxExecuteBlocking(future -> {
    try {
      final Optional<Device> device = Optional.ofNullable(engine.get().getDeviceForRequest(userAgent));
      future.complete(device.map(d -> new DeviceInfo()));
    } catch (final RuntimeException e) {
      LOGGER.error("Unable to get the UA device info {}, reason {}", userAgent, e.getMessage());
      future.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
  });
}
```